# Boost beast read: The WebSocket control frame was fragmented

Tags: c++, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

While I am trying the code from:
[advanced_server example](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/5bdd1efb8be740bb5425adc054c990818134f3e2/example/advanced/server/advanced_server.cpp)
I am getting following error [here](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/5bdd1efb8be740bb5425adc054c990818134f3e2/example/advanced/server/advanced_server.cpp#L295):

`read: The WebSocket control frame was fragmented`

The client is sending ping control message using [`Poco`](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html) framework. The payload is of zero bytes length.

What could be the issue?